# reading rtsp stream using ffmpeg (latest) api

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp

can anyone guide me how to capture rtsp stream data using ffmpeg latest api. The examples are not compiling on the latest ffmpeg 0.8 release.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you posted the compile errors.

Comment: Which examples are not compiling? ffplay or ffmpeg or something else?